# Reset SSRS parameters when date parameter changes

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-2012

I have 4 user defined parameters on my report - date (defaults to today()) and three others. I would like it so that when the date parameter is changed to another date by the user, the other 3 parameters are reset back to their default values.

I cannot seem to figure out how to do it. I've read about cascading parameters, but I'm not sure that is how to go about accomplishing this task.

What is the best way to get this done? Right now, when you change the date, the other parameters stay the same, which is not what my user would like to see.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I have not tried this trick but I have seen it accomplished and it is a little tricky.

[Boyan Penev](http://www.bp-msbi.com/2011/04/ssrs-cascading-parameters-refresh-solved/) has an explanation that is quite elaborate and innovative. While the first part of the parameter selection is text and not a date I am sure that it can be adapted to fit your needs

Here is a summary:

> 1. Create a new Data Source pointing to the database containing out
>      tables and stored procedures;
> 2. Create a Data Set p1 for the parent parameter;
> 3. Create a @p1 report parameter (multi-select, text) with available
>      values obtained from the usp_p1 stored procedure (p1k as Value, p1l
>      as Label);
> 4. Create a Data Set p2 for the dependent parameter, which accepts @p1
>      as a parameter;
> 5. Create a @p2 report parameter (multi-select, text) with available
>      and default values obtained from the usp_p2 procedure (p2k as Value,
>      p2l as Label).
> 6. Set the @p2 report parameter to be Internal;
> 7. Create a @p3 report parameter (multi-select, text), with Available
>      Values Value expression of =Parameters!p2.Value and Label of
>      =Parameters!p2.Label. The Default Values should be =Parameters!p2.Value;
> 8. Create a Data Set main from the usp_main stored procedure and make sure that its parameter is populated by @p3, not @p2;
> 9. Add a table in the report with two columns, which show p2l and amt from the main data set.

Like I said a bit complicated but I am sure that will some messing around you can adapt the strategy to your needs.

Hope this helped!